# sending Date using moment to graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, momentjs

I am trying to send a mutation to my graphql server to update a date. My mutation schema looks like this:

```
mutation CreateReminderMutation(
    $birthday: Date
) {
    createReminder(
        birthday: $birthday
    ) {
        id
    }
}
```

Then in my react component I am sending the date like this using `moment`.

```
const Calendar = () => {
   // component and mutation implementation
   birthday: moment(birthday).toDate()
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$birthday" got invalid value
>   "2019-03-15T12:00:00.000Z"; Expected type Date; Value is not a valid
>   Date: 2019-03-15T12:00:00.000Z, unparsable, Location: [object Object],
>   Path: undefined

can anyone advise how to get the correct `Date` format with moment to send to graphql?

Comment: why has this been downvoted without any explanation? If it was an obvious easy solution I would have found it

Comment: well, toDate seems to be exactly what you should be doing, that's for sure, as toDate returns a copy of the native Date object - it's odd that the error also states that date string is unparsable - I mean, that is THE guaranteed parsable string format for a date

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX at least I am not going completely crazy. can't find much in the graphql docs about this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [graphql-iso-date](https://github.com/excitement-engineer/graphql-iso-date) package, a `Date` scalar needs to be in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. So your mutation would be like:

```
mutation {
  createReminder(birthday: "1990-01-01") {
    id
  }
}
```

See this codesandbox: https://m5782nj1w9.sse.codesandbox.io/?query=query%20%7B%0A%20%20daysAgo%28when%3A%20%222018-01-01%22%29%0A%7D

Answer (score 3):

No moment.js solution but this works for me using graphql prisma

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `toISOString()` method returns the "simplified **extended** ISO format" which is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString))

To get the `YYYY-MM-DD` ISO 8601 string, you need

```
 new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0],
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `new Date().toUTCString()` for hasura deployed on heroku. This did not work for me `new Date().toISOString()`